# New version of entity framework designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I've seen in this article 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/11/entity-designer-improvements-preview.aspx 
that a new version of entity framework designer is planned.

Does anyone know when this one would be released ?

Thank's by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be shipped only with the next version of VS, because of new recently added features of the the product are either not reflected in VS shipping plan or in VS2010 SP1, because it will require some FW support just like new cx0++ features drafts.

Comment: And is there any way to implement multiple edmx feature in actual version of ef ?

Comment: @Artur Mustafin you can add the enum feature and others inprovements listed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/11/entity-designer-improvements-preview.aspx just install these files: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26660 so change the target framework in project properties to "Framework June 2011 CTP"

Answer (score 0):

I have this upgraded EF Designer in my **VS2010 SP1**
I Just Install alls *msi in this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26660

[image]
[image]